A pair of BP FIR filters with the phase response difference of \pi and equal magnitude
I came across a pair of bandpass FIR filters with identical frequency response and phase response differing by $\pi$. The pair is defined by coefficients with opposite signs, i.e.,
$h_{A}[1] + h_{B}[1] = 0$ for all 32 coefficients.
I'm wondering what could be a use case for such a filter.
Would appreciate any references to relevant literature.

I don't really see any advantage, since $h_A \cdot -1= h_B$ anyways.Wherever you'd need that, you just multiply the output of one filter with $-1$ to get the other.
